# Task Scheduler Having Issues Running CMD file that works when its run manually

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I have a script to delete all files in my Epson Scans Folder. If I run the script manually it works perfectly. But for some reason if I set up a task in task scheduler it does not delete the files? Does anyone know why this would happen?

Note: pclist.txt is just a list of pc names

```
@echo off

for /F %%G in (pclist.txt) do ( 

pushd "\\%%G\C$\Epson Scans" || exit /B 1
for /D %%I in ("*") do (
    rd /S /Q "%%~I"
)
del /Q "*"
popd

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the file pclist.txt is located in 'probably' the `\Windows\system32` directory?

When run as a Scheduled task the current directory will not necessarily be that used when run as a user.

The easiest way to achieve that is is to put that full path within those parentheses or to add the following line just beneath the `@echo off`.

```
IF "%CD%\" NEQ "%~dp0" PUSHD "%~dp0"
```